# Incorrectly scaled menu checkmarks on High DPI using .Net 4.8/Windows Forms

Tags: winforms, menu, highdpi, .net-4.8

Using .Net 4.8 and Windows Forms, my toolstrip menus with check marks appear normally at 100%, but when the monitor is set to something larger (e.g. 150%), the menu check mark appears far too small, and located in the upper-left of the menu item.

Is there a way to override the painting of the check mark for use on high DPI monitors?

(Using per-monitor DPI scaling, all other form controls draw correctly thanks to the scaling improvements starting in .Net 4.7.2

Comment: Lots of Bitmaps/Drawings are not scaled . You can handle it yourself: [ToolStripProfessionalRenderer Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.toolstriprenderer.drawitemcheck), [ToolStripProfessionalRenderer.OnRenderItemCheck](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.toolstripprofessionalrenderer.onrenderitemcheck) and friends.

Comment: You can also disable the ToolStrip scaling, See in `App.Config`, `<System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationConfigurationSection>` `Toolstrip.DisableHighDpiImprovements` (and friends :)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem wasn't *really* the checkmarks at all; it was the imagealign of the menu item (apparently, used to align the checkmark when there is no menu image) Setting that to be centered fixed the issue.